# Error Compiling Bitcoin Core on OS X

Tags: mac, compiling

I am running OS X Yosemite. I cloned the [bitcoin repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) and checkout-ed the v0.9.3 tag to get the most recent stable version.

Then I followed the steps described [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md) to compile the code.

It compiled for a long time, and then ended with the following error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [test_bitcoin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Has anyone seen this error before? Why was it caused? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What messages do you see before that?

Comment: [Related issue on Bitcoin bug tracker](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3228). Have you tried recompiling [boost according to this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888327/using-boost-on-xcode-5-apple-llvm-5-0)?

Comment: @Nick, I put the console output into https://github.com/Ziftr/bitcoin/blob/testing/console_error.txt. I tried doing something similar to that link you suggested, but I will try it again. Thanks.

Comment: [I think this guy had the same problem as you.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/5064) You can apply the patch manually, or just `git checkout master`

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: That does seem like the same issue, but I ended up getting a docker container image that worked. Takes forever to compile, but probably no getting around that. Will revisit this issue when I get a chance.